# Text Editor, Python Module Won't "Unload"

Tags: python, text-editor

I am writing a Python script for Blender and I'm using the text editor window to run it.

My code includes a line that imports a module (import ILD_Blender) that I have written and need to trouble shoot.

I have no problem running the script but when I make a change to ILD_Blender and run the script again, it does not contain the changes I just made to the module ILD_Blender . The script runs the "previous" version.

Under Edit/Preferences../Add-ons, the module is installed and is checked off. It sounds to me that this module loads on Blender start-up and is unaltered even if I change the actual file that is loaded.

So, How do I update the loaded module while still in Blender?

Bob B.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: Do you have an [unregister function](https://wiki.blender.org/wiki/Reference/Release_Notes/2.80/Python_API/Addons) that calls `bpy.utils.unregister_class` for each class you've registered?

Comment: OK, this post shows my limited knowledge of Blender! What I need to do when I make a change to a module already installed as a Blender add-on, I need to perform a "Reload Scripts". Problem solved.